# Randomly sized UICollectionViewCell circle design

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to have a collection view with randomly sized cells but each cell is circle. An example mockup is shown below.. The question is

how would I go about doing this?

[image: screen]

**Edit:** The design doesn't have to be a UICollectionView, I just assumed this would be the best way to do it.. I'm definitely open to any way about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also think using a `UICollectionView` is a good idea. You would definitely have to implement a custom flow layout to be able to organize these random sized cells. Maybe taking a look at [CCHexagonFlowLayout](https://github.com/cyrilchandelier/CCHexagonFlowLayout) and [MosaicLayout](https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout) could help. As for drawing the circles inside the cells, you could have a square `UIView` in the cell and set `circleView.layer.cornerRadius` to half of its height.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. I guess the real question I was asking is how to make them fit together like the picture since the cells are all squares, so the CCHexagonFlowLayout is perfect.

Comment: Hi Jacob , Do you solve this problem , I tried to use Hexagon but I need different sizes , how can I do this ? Thanks , Nada Gamal

Answer (score 0):

The collection view is a pretty good idea.  Using the flow layout, you can implement [collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:).  Answer a random square size ([see arc4random_uniform()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html)).

Within each cell, inscribe a circle.  The simplest way to do that (at least for a start) is a UIImageView whose frame fills the cell bounds and whose content mode is set to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.  All you need then is a picture of a circle.